# Model gets distorted when rotating the camera

Tags: opengl, 3d, graphics, python, 3d-meshes

I'm currently developing my own 3d graphics engine and I'm having a hard time figuring out why my 3D models gets distorted when rotating the camera around.

This is my projection matrix. I'm following the OpenGL's Model.

```
def get_projection_mat(aspect_ratio, camera):  
    fov = camera.fov  
    z_near = camera.z_near  
    z_far = camera.z_far  
    top = math.tan(fov * 0.5) * z_near  
    bottom = -top  
    right = top * aspect_ratio  
    left = -right  
    projection_mat = np.identity(4, dtype=float)  
    projection_mat[0, 0] = 2 * z_near / (right - left)  
    projection_mat[0, 2] = (right + left) / (right - left)  
    projection_mat[1, 1] = 2 * z_near / (top - bottom)  
    projection_mat[1, 2] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom)  
    projection_mat[2, 2] = -(z_far + z_near) / (z_far - z_near)  
    projection_mat[2, 3] = -2 * z_far * z_near / (z_far - z_near)  
    projection_mat[3, 2] = -1  
    projection_mat[3, 3] = 0  

    return projection_mat
```

This is my view matrix:

```
def camera_matrix(self):  
    camera_matrix = np.identity(4, dtype=float)  
    camera_matrix[:3, 0] = self.left[:]  
    camera_matrix[:3, 1] = self.up[:]  
    camera_matrix[:3, 2] = self.forward[:]  
    camera_matrix[:3, 3] = self.pos[:]  

    return camera_matrix
```

This is how I get the ViewProjection matrix:

```
    projection_mat = get_projection_mat(self.aspect_ratio, self.camera)  
    view_mat = self.camera.camera_matrix()  
    view_mat = np.linalg.inv(view_mat)  
    self.view_projection_mat = np.dot(projection_mat, view_mat)
```

And, finally, this is the ViewProjectionModel matrix:

```
    view_projection_model_mat = np.dot(model.transform_mat.T, self.view_projection_mat)
```

This is the method that I use to rotate the camera:

```
def rotate(self, yaw, pitch, degress=True):  
    rotation_mat_y = helper.rotate_matrix_y(yaw, degrees)  
    rotation_mat_x = helper.rotate_matrix_x(pitch, degrees)  
    rotation_mat = np.dot(rotation_mat_y, rotation_mat_x)  
    self.forward = np.dot(np.insert(self.forward, 3, 1), rotation_mat)  
    self.forward = helper.normalized((self.forward / self.forward[3])[:3])  
    self.up = np.dot(np.insert(self.up, 3, 1), rotation_mat)  
    self.up = helper.normalized((self.up / self.up[3])[:3])  
    self.left = np.dot(np.insert(self.left, 3, 1), rotation_mat)  
    self.left = helper.normalized((self.left / self.left[3])[:3])
```

A video demo, showing the [problem](https://youtu.be/JakDWOM9x18)

To summarize, the order of multiplication is ProjectionMat X ViewMat x ModelMat x ModelFaces.
If it isn't clear by now, I'm using Python for this project.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

With best regards,
João Pedro

**EDIT**: Like this?

```
    directions, r = np.linalg.qr(np.array([self.forward, self.up, self.left]))  
    self.forward = directions[0]  
    self.up = directions[1]  
    self.left = directions[2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential errors here:

1. You're transforming directions like they're points.

   `np.insert(self.forward, 3, 1)` says "Add a homogenouse coordinate of 1 to this direction vector so that matrix translation affects it" - but you absolutely *do not* want translation to affect your directions! Turning 30 degrees is turning 30 degrees, no matter whether I do it at the origin or 50 km away from the origin.

   Your translation is already tracked by the `pos` variable, so don't let it leak into your directions this way. Instead, your 4th component / "w" of a direction vector should be zero, to ensure you factor in only the rotation of the vector.

   This also makes the division by w unnecessary, though you were already obliterating its result by normalizing it anyway.
2. You're allowing rounding errors to accumulate

   `forward`, `up`, and `left` are used as inputs to compute their own successors, meaning that any error in the input gets replicated in the output, along with any new rounding errors from the latest multiplication / normalization. So each small incremental error adds up and gradually snowballs up to a perceptible scale.

   You're re-normalizing the vectors, so you're correcting any errors in their lengths, but not their directions. [So as the errors build up, the three basis vectors drift from being fully orthogonal, causing the skewing artifacts you're seeing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114284/39518).

   To fix this, you'll want to [orthonormalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) your basis to correct both magnitude and directional errors and stop them from building up. One way to do this is using the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). You can compute the `left` vector from the cross product of `up` and `forward` to get a mutually-perpendicular unit vector by construction with a bit less work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already fixed the 1º point. But something that i didn't grasp is, where I'm supposed to do the orthonormalization? To the camera's rotation matrix? To the vecto's itself? I've already tried making a column matrix out of my directions,orthonormalizating it and extracting the camera's directions, but things got a little too funky. I'm quite frustated at this point :P.

Comment: Do it when you update forward, up, and left, ie. in your rotate method.

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: I think that's heavier-weight than you need, given that you're discarding r anyway, but if it works for you then it works for you.

Comment: Had forgotten to mark as solved, my bad